# Javascript add link text when adding table rows

Tags: javascript, html

i have this JS and HTML Code:

when you click the add button it runs the below function to add another row to the HTML table and adds more form fields with numbers after counting up 1 each time

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var i=2;
function addRow()
{
          var tbl = document.getElementById('table1');
          var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
          var iteration = lastRow - 1;
          var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

          var productcodeCell = row.insertCell(0);
          var elproductcode = document.createElement('input');
          elproductcode.type = 'text';
          elproductcode.name = 'productcode' + i;
          elproductcode.id = 'productcode' + i;
          elproductcode.size = 20;
          productcodeCell.appendChild(elproductcode);

          var producttitleCell = row.insertCell(1);
          var elproducttitle = document.createElement('input');
          elproducttitle.type = 'text';
          elproducttitle.name = 'producttitle' + i;
          elproducttitle.id = 'producttitle' + i;
          elproducttitle.size = 30;
          producttitleCell.appendChild(elproducttitle);

          var quantityCell = row.insertCell(2);
          var elQuantity = document.createElement('input');
          elQuantity.type = 'text';
          elQuantity.name = 'quantity' + i;
          elQuantity.id = 'quantity' + i;
          elQuantity.size = 10;
          quantityCell.appendChild(elQuantity);

          i++;
          form1.number.value=i;
          //alert(i);

}
</script>

<form method="post" action="create_quote2.php" name="form1">
<input type="button" value="Add New Line" onclick="addRow();" />
<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Product Code</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Add</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Qty</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="productcode1" id="productcode1" size="20" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="producttitle1" id="producttitle1" size="30" /></td>
    <td><a href="page.php?c=1">Link here</a></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantity1" id="quantity1" size="10" /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="number" id="number" value="1" />
    </form>
```

how can i add a link in the 3rd column when a row is added also changing the end number in the URL + 1 each time like the other fields

Comment: It appears that you could follow the same approach in incrementing the link num as you are with i... or why not just simply use i? Is the question about how to build a link and concatenate the value of i within the link string?

Comment: sorry - how to build the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try setting up a variable containing a static link string with i concatenated. Appending the variable where needed should seem familiar given the rest of your script.

```
var i=2;
function addRow()
{
    var link='/directoryname/filename'+i+'.html';
```

The new link cell can be built and appended as so:

```
var linkCell = row.insertCell(2);
var elLink = document.createElement('a');
var href='/directoryname/filename'+i+'.html';
elLink.href = href;
elLink.innerHTML = 'link'+i;
linkCell.appendChild(elLink);
```

I've added a jsfiddle for you to examine: http://jsfiddle.net/KKKZ8/

Comment: what do i put in the HTML?